# php.exe is missing. gone

Tags: php, windows, xampp, environment

OS: Windows 10

yesterday I install xampp because I want to learn laravel.

everything is normal. I setup laravel and all. and I got to develop some progress.

before I went to sleep, I turn off my laptop.

in the morning, I open my project and run `php artisan serve`. then I got

```bash
'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I try to check my environment. I found that PHP is gone from the environment. so I add PHP (again) in the environment table.

and still, got the same error

```bash
'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

so I check the path `C:/xampp/php`. turns out, there is no `php.exe`

then I run `where php.exe` from cmd in the directory `C:/`. and got

```bash
C:\>where php.exe
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
```

Is there any solution so I can use PHP again?

Comment: Check your anti-virus software and make sure it's not killing it, if it is uninstall the bag of excrement AV and install a decent one :D

Comment: Copy the htdocs folder in xampp to another location. Uninstall xampp and reinstall. Then move the previously copied files to the newly installed Xampp's htdocs folder. Or if you know the php version, you can just simply download it from the web and replace your php folder.

Comment: Download the version of php from here: https://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/